# Can I assign position of item in list?

Tags: list, python-3.7

```
ex = ['$5','Amazon','spoon']
```

I want to re-order this list, website - item - price.
Can I assign the index, for instance, `ex.index('Amazon') = 1`?

I'd like the result to be `['Amazon','spoon','$5']`

I found information on how to swap positions, but I would like to know if I can assign an index for each item myself.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot assign an index to an item, but you can build a permuted list according to a permutation pattern:

```
ex = ['$5','Amazon','spoon']
order = [1, 2, 0]
ex_new = [ex[i] for i in order]
print(ex_new)
#['Amazon', 'spoon', '$5']
```

Alternatively, you can overwrite the original list in place:

```
ex[:] = [ex[i] for i in order]
print(ex)
#['Amazon', 'spoon', '$5']
```